# How can I set script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; for specific page or path in play framework 2.6.x?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have been trying to set a text editor in my web app. Where to access the text editor I have to allow script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' and style-src 'unsafe-inline'. But in playframework 2.6.x i have to set this by
`play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy` in config file which makes the whole app insecure.

Note: meta tag does not work, even I tried to pass Content-security-policy in response header by filter. Nothing works.

In this case is there any way of setting `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' and style-src 'unsafe-inline'` for any specific page or path in play 2.6.x?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the [Silhouette Seed Template](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed)

```
# Security Filter Configuration - Content Security Policy
play.filters.headers {
  contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self';"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" img-src 'self' *.fbcdn.net *.twimg.com *.googleusercontent.com *.xingassets.com vk.com *.yimg.com secure.gravatar.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.googleapis.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com;"
  contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" connect-src 'self' twitter.com *.xing.com;"
}
```

**Play 2.7**
On a certain Action it looks like:

```
Ok("Index").withHeaders(SecurityHeadersFilter.REFERRER_POLICY -> "my page-specific header")
```

Check the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/SecurityHeaders#Action-specific-overrides

However in **Play 2.7** this is deprecated - use CSP instead - see: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/CspFilter#Enabling-CSP-on-Specific-Actions

There is also a possibility (on the same doc) to exclude a `route` from the CSP filter, like:

```
+ nocsp
POST     /report-to                 controllers.CSPReportController.report
```

Comment: I think this will be applied for all the responses of app. Is there way of specifying for any intended response?

Comment: check my answer - I couldn't find it for Play 2.6 though.

Comment: "exclude a route from the CSP filter" with `+ nocsrf` tag? Typo?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov +nocsrf means no Cross-Site Request Forgery filter, where +nocsp means no Security content policy  on path